# How to put 2 or more values into ArrayList<NameValuePair>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I would like to know how to put multiplevalues into `ArrayList<NameValuePair>`.This is my Code but it doesn't working.Someone help explain me about `ArraysList<NameValuePair>`.
Here's My Code:

```
public void OnClickForSave(View v) throws Exception {
    String st = null;
    String str = null;
    String response = null;
    String memberID = "000000007";
    String teamID = "000007";
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", memberID));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("teamID", teamID));

    if (v.getId() == (R.id.imgbtn_layout2)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntentTesting.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    if (v.getId() == (R.id.imgbtn_lsave)) {
        if (txt_teamID.getText().toString().trim().equals(null)
                || txt_teamID.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            AlertDialog empty = createDialogEmpty(this, "Enter Team ID");
            empty.show();
            txt_teamID.selectAll();
            txt_teamID.requestFocus();
        }
        else if (txt_teamID.getText().toString().trim().length() > 6) {
            AlertDialog notFormat = createDialogEmpty(this, "More Than 6 Characters");
            txt_teamID.selectAll();
            txt_teamID.requestFocus();
            notFormat.show();
        } else {
            try {
                st = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("http://192.168.200.14/football365/DBConnection.php");
                str = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("http://192.168.200.14/football365/responseJson.php");
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.200.14/football/joinTeam.php",
                        postParameters);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost`? A standard library or your own class and method?

Answer (score 1):

Sup buddy?
Just use the add function of the params in this case. It's not mandatory to initialize with a specific size.

`List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Key1", "Value1"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Key2", "Value"));`

You will have something like this

Key1 = Value1; 
Key2 = Value

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
```

You need to initialize your ArrayLists with the data type that the list will store.

After this just use:

```
ArrayList.add(element e);
```

You can call this method as many times as necessary.

Comment: would you mind rewriting my code pls . I don't know .Really Sorry

Comment: Thanks foyour patient :)

Comment: Does class BasicNameValuePair extend class NameValuePair? I'm not familiar with Android applications.

Comment: Ok then I suggest doing a console debug print like: System.out.println("ArrayList size: "+postParameters.size()); Right after you add your elements to see if the add method isn't working. I'm assuming that your errors are elsewhere though

Answer (score 0):

Try thi code as below

`List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID",memberID));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("teamID",teamID));`

It work for me.